# How to record audio and video corss platform with electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, electron

So i was making a electron project that records your screen and your desktop or selected app's audio with desktopCapture.
I got the screen record, and at one point even got the mic to work, but at no point, no matter what i tried, i couldn't record desktop audio nor any app's audio. After some research i found that you cannot record any desktop nor app's audio with chromium on linux.

So what could be the solution or some other ways to try to record desktop audio. Maybe there is some way to record desktop audio with a different library and then combine the video with audio somehow.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Code for the screen recorder itself:

```
videoSelectBtn.onclick = getVideoSources;

async function getVideoSources() {
  const inputSources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
    types: ["window", "screen", "audio"],
  });

  inputSources.forEach((source) => {
    if (source.name === "Screen 1") {
      selectSource(source);
    } else {
      console.log(source);
    }
  });
}

async function selectSource(source) {
  videoSelectBtn.innerText = source.name;

  const constraints = {
    audio: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
      },
    },
    video: {
      mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
      },
    },
  };

  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

  videoElement.srcObject = stream;
  videoElement.play();

  const options = {
    mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp9",
  };
  mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;
  mediaRecorder.onstop = handleStop;
}

function handleDataAvailable(e) {
  console.log("video data available");
  recordedChunks.push(e.data);
}

async function handleStop(e) {
  const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
    type: "video/webm; codecs=vp9",
  });

  const buffer = Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer());

  const { filePath } = await dialog.showSaveDialog({
    buttonLabel: "Save video",
    defaultPath: `vid-${Date.now()}.webm`,
  });

  if (filePath) {
    writeFile(filePath, buffer, () => console.log("video saved successfully!"));
  }
}
```